# IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: html, python-2.7

I have a data list which I got from splitting html with regex.

```
data_list = re.findall(r'<tr.*?>(.*?)<\/tr>', html)
```

When I loop in data_list I want to defining variable open for example

```
open = re.findall(r'kurs".*?>(.*?)<\/td', x)[0].strip('</span>')
```

and it gives me an error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 2, in 
>       open = re.findall(r'kurs".*?>(.*?)</td', x)[0].strip('')
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that an element with such an index doesn't exist in the list. So there is no first element in the list re.findall returned, and this means it found nothing.

By the way, it is not recommended to use regular expressions for parsing HTML, better use HTML-oriented frameworks like BeautifulSoup and lxml.